# Phusion Passenger Rails not balancing request across workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

Below is the output when I run passenger-status on the server

```
Requests in queue: 0
 * PID: 1821    Sessions: 0       Processed: 2971    Uptime: 15m 11s
   CPU: 14%     Memory  : 416M    Last used: 0s ago
 * PID: 1847    Sessions: 0       Processed: 1066    Uptime: 15m 11s
   CPU: 6%      Memory  : 256M    Last used: 2s ago
 * PID: 1861    Sessions: 0       Processed: 199     Uptime: 15m 11s
   CPU: 1%      Memory  : 238M    Last used: 3s ago
 * PID: 1875    Sessions: 0       Processed: 37      Uptime: 15m 10s
   CPU: 0%      Memory  : 196M    Last used: 15s ago
 * PID: 1900    Sessions: 0       Processed: 7       Uptime: 15m 10s
   CPU: 0%      Memory  : 136M    Last used: 33s ago
 * PID: 1916    Sessions: 0       Processed: 4       Uptime: 15m 10s
   CPU: 0%      Memory  : 126M    Last used: 33s ago
 * PID: 1932    Sessions: 0       Processed: 1       Uptime: 15m 10s
   CPU: 0%      Memory  : 132M    Last used: 14m 44s ago
 * PID: 1946    Sessions: 0       Processed: 0       Uptime: 15m 10s
   CPU: 0%      Memory  : 68M     Last used: 15m 10s ago
 * PID: 1962    Sessions: 0       Processed: 0       Uptime: 15m 9s
   CPU: 0%      Memory  : 53M     Last used: 15m 9s ago
 * PID: 1980    Sessions: 0       Processed: 0       Uptime: 15m 9s
   CPU: 0%      Memory  : 53M     Last used: 15m 9s ago
```

The stack we are running is Nginx + Passenger + Rails.
My concern here is as the docs say passenger must be distributing load across the workers present spawned by itself, but as we can see from the logs, only the top 2 workers get all the requests, the rest are just idle.

Also with time the Memory usage by top workers increases.
Is this an expected behaviour?
How can I rectify this, and can I improve performance in any way?

Also my passenger conf is below

```
  passenger_max_pool_size 20;
  passenger_min_instances 10;
  passenger_max_instances_per_app 0;
  passenger_pre_start <api-endpoint>;
  passenger_pool_idle_time 0;
  passenger_max_request_queue_size 0;
```

Comment: we're actually getting this as well, hope somebody could answer this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me, I made a comment a few minutes ago and now I found the answer.

Summary: Passenger uses a simple algorithm to fill up the top request whenever possible instead of using round robin, nothing wrong with your application.

The link explains most of it.

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/ruby/request_load_balancing.html#traffic-may-appear-unbalanced-between-processes